# Why Int16.CompareTo returns different result from Int32.CompareTo

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.6.2

I have two unit tests and both are valid. So, why `Int16.CompateTo` returns difference between two numbers, while `Int32` and `Int64` `CompareTo` method returns strictly `-1, 0, 1`?

```
[TestMethod]
public void Int16CompareTo()
{
    Int16 value1 = 60;
    Int16 value2 = 5;
    var result = value1.CompareTo(value2);
    Assert.AreEqual(result, 55);
}

[TestMethod]
public void Int32CompareTo()
{
    Int32 value1 = 60;
    Int32 value2 = 5;
    var result = value1.CompareTo(value2);
    Assert.AreEqual(result, 1);
}
```

Comment: Because they're implemented differently, and your test is wrong. The result of `IComparable.CompareTo` is negative, zero or positive. The *specific value* it returns is implementation-defined and should not be tested for.

Comment: The reference source [helpfully documents](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,49) why `Int32` and `Int64` do not simply subtract: to handle overflow. `Int16` does subtract, and doesn't have the same problem because the arguments are implicitly promoted to `Int32` first. Although it's a bit silly of the developers to use that fact.

Answer (score 0):

The MSN documentation is reflecting the behavior you are receiving. All the methods guarantee is that you will get a value greater than 0 if the number is larger. 0 if the number is equal and less then 0 if the number is less.

If you want I would override the method or create a new one for test cases.

32 bit
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2ky8xsk(v=vs.110).aspx

16 bit
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06x7xh8y(v=vs.110).aspx